# Create a NFData instance for Trie

Tags: haskell

I'm currently working on a project using the [vcache-trie](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/vcache-trie-0.2.4) module. I'm looking to test the execution speed of a research inside the trie with the `lookupPrefix` function.

This is a benchmark created with Criterion for this purpose :

```
bench "trieSearch"  $ nf (lookupPrefix (pack "ab")) trie
```

where trie is created in an environment for criterion. The type of this trie is `Trie Int`.

As the environment is evaluated to normal form I need to create an instance of [NFData](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.4.3.0/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#t:NFData) for this specific type.

The content of the trie for this specific case is [(ByteString, Int)], I assume the instance of NFData should evaluate each tuple but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help would be greatly appreciate, thanks for taking the time to read my issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following should do the trick, but may be slightly less efficient than writing an `NFData` with access to the internal representation (as suggested by @JonPurdy):

```
instance NFData a => NFData (Trie a) where rnf = rnf . toList
```

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should contact the maintainer of `vcache-trie` with a feature request or patch to add the instance, since you would need access to the internal representation of `Trie` in order to write it.

As a workaround, you can make a locally modified version of the package (e.g., adding a local checkout to `extra-deps` in Stack) and either add an `NFData` instance yourself, or add `deriving (Generic)` to `Trie` and use `deepseq-generics` to implement `NFData`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, it's working with the workaround. I will contact the maintainer as suggested.

Comment: @Barbrousse, I'm not sure an `NFData` instance will really get you what you want in this case. From the documentation: "The primary motivation for VRefs is to support memory-cached values, i.e. very large data structures that should not be stored in all at once in RAM." I don't think it's very likely that you'll be able to get a really meaningful sense of the performance of an operation by performing a `deepseq` on the result. That said, the package should probably offer an `NFData` instance anyway.

Comment: @dfeuer Thanks for your response, do you have any idea of a more accurate test that could be created for this case ?

Comment: @Barbrousse Presumably the most accurate thing is to test not just the creation of the trie, but also whatever code you think is most representative of the way you will be consuming that same trie. Then you won't need an `NFData` instance for the trie, either.